# Git as a backup and Version Control System

Tags: git

I want to use Git to backup my home drive, but I also want to use it as a version control system for projects that will be stored in my home drive.

How would I go about doing that? Do I .gitignore all the projects root folders and make new repositories for them?

Edit:

Ok I explained what I wanted wrongly.  I want to have a history of changes made to my home drive like I can get with Git and I also want to back that up.

Comment: That isn't what Git is for, it's a version control system.

Comment: Using git to back up a drive is massive overkill.

Comment: @rogeriopvl - no. it isn't overkill ... which would imply something else ... like using git to version control a script of three lines. git - it is just not the tool for the job. git is not a backup system.

Comment: What kind of storage do you want to use for your backup?

Comment: Yes, having fully visibility and granular control over periodic changes to entire fs broken down into atomic commits and logs with incremental updates is a TERRIBLE idea and the cost of knowing a few git commands is simply too high

Answer (score 20):

I [wrote a blog post about this](http://blog.codekills.net/archives/70-Using-git-for-Backup-is-Asking-for-Pain.html) a while back:

> Version control systems, with the possible exception of SourceSafe, are great at keeping track of code. Why is that? Because they were *designed to keep track of code*.
>
> Unfortunately, though, the features of a good VCS are *entirely different* – and often *exactly the opposite* – of the features which make a good backup system.
>
> Take, for example, *file ownership*. A good VCS will, very rightly, *ignore file ownership*: when I check out someone else's code, I should be the owner of those file - not whatever uid originally created them. A good backup system, on the other hand, will do *everything in its power to preserve file ownership*: when I restore from my backups, I want /etc/shaddow to be owned by root and /home/wolever/ to be owned by wolever.

BUT, if you really want to, check out [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup) - as far as I can tell, it does backup with `git` "right".

Comment: Please add some snippets from the article in order to prevent [link rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140772/link-rot-encourage-author-to-cache-snippets-of-relevant-text-to-prepare-for-thi).

Comment: bup looks great except that it also looks severely underdeveloped :/

Answer (score 18):

Use `rsync` for backup.
Use `git` for version control.

Comment: @mk Explaining why would be useful. Why would you not use 'git clone' and 'git pull' to sync/backup?

Comment: i use git for backup AND verison control, using .gitignore to control separation, the only issue with backup is if your pc crashes mid commit it can corrupt your repo and break the backup, until that happens though it is a great idea, rolling back broken installations is too easy lol

Answer (score 3):

You really want to use rsync to backup your data.
Check out the following url for more information on rsync and also some examples on how to backup your data:

http://www.sanitarium.net/golug/rsync_backups_2010.html

Answer (score 3):

I've found the backintime-gnome (glade/python, separate backend?) to be good for scheduled incremental backups, it works for your daily, weekly, monthly etc.. Then Git repos for source files or other change-critical data would wrap it up nice. I haven't played with the bachintime-common backend commands but they all seem to be python.

I'm using it in Ubuntu, "Keep in mind that Back In Time is just a GUI. The real magic is done by rsync (take snapshots and restore), diff (check if somethind changed) and cp (make hardlinks)." -http://backintime.le-web.org/documentation/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few projects that aim to solve that problem:

bup seems to have made the most progress: https://github.com/apenwarr/bup

But you may also want to search for gibak or coldstorage.

Comment: I am searching for a new backup tool for some weeks. This project (bup) looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Great idea, i actually use it daily and it works *fantastic* until your pc crashes mid-commit and corrupts your repo. First time that happened it took me a day to fix everything and restore backups, you end up learning quite a bit about git internals in the process so that's an added benefit. Assuming you're on linux, I recommend having a local copy of the .git dir backed up on a separate drive or whatever, then git init at the / root of your os and use .gitignore to control what gets versioned. Some files are "special" so you probably wanna exclude them by default, like stuff in /proc. You can watch exactly what different software is doing to your fs and rolling back broken installations and keeping track of configuration, logs, etc. is a breeze. I don't know why all these nay-sayers are saying "don't do it" because I did it and it's very practical and very awesome. Like I said only downside is corrupted repo when something unexpected happens, but if you prepare for that fixing a broken commit is just a matter of copying the pre-corrupted .git over the corrupted one.

Answer (score 0):

That reads pretty much like what I'm doing. I have a git repository in my home directory, but I use that to track only those configuration files that I can edit by hand. (This rules out state files kept by "modern" desktop environments and almost everything that is stored as XML.) Everything else goes into `.gitignore`. Once upon a time, I decided that my "notes" directory and my `~/.emacs.d` should go into their own repositories, so I created git repositories in those directories and had the main repository ignore them.

I don't use this setup for backup purposes but to synchronize the tracked files between accounts on different machines, but I suppose that this could also work for backups.

Comment: Well, it's possible, but for synchronisation/backup purposes rsync will work a lot better.

Comment: No.

rsync has no sensible solution for me if I edit the same file on two different accounts. (unison which uses rsync's algorithm does, but it fails in other problems.) At least, git can detect and merge conflicting edits. rsync also has no answer to the question "what did file X look like 14 days ago?"

Answer (score 0):

On windows git-extensions as well as the gitGui allow you to clone a repository, which would allow you to make a backup without all the files in .gitignore.

Next 7zip it up and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

For the projects that you want to keep a close track or make some rollback, you can use git in a normal way.

If you want to upload projects with large files and you don't want to be able to checkout to previous commits in order to get old files, you can use `git lfs`. This will make the `.git` folder much smaller if to make changes on large files:

> [**Git Large File Storage (LFS)**](https://git-lfs.github.com/) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

This solution would be an approach to have a Git Project as a backup. Or even you can use both in a same project, tracking and keep changes only with the files you want.